# Different "Already has an answer" links

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Having a bit of an odd time with this question:
[Is there any difference with using only location vs using window.location across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/window-foo-vs-foo-notation)

It's been closed as a duplicate of the following questions: [Javascript: Setting location.href versus location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-window-location-href-versus-window-location) and [What is the difference between document.location.href and document.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652816/what-is-the-difference-between-document-location-href-and-document-location) both of which are incorrect duplicates:
[image]

However in one of the comments, Quantas64Heavy mentions that for them, [window.location versus just location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709037/window-location-versus-just-location?rq=1) is the first result - which is a perfectly valid duplicate I didn't find during my original search.

Just wondering why they would have a different view of the above screen than I had?

Comment: This question was reopened yesterday, but the links should still be visible on the history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/is-there-any-difference-with-using-only-location-vs-using-window-location-across#comment33562048_19423513):

> @Tmdean: it's still a duplicate regardless, for example the first question in the "related" list. [window.location versus just location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709037/window-location-versus-just-location?rq=1)

The user who posted the comments did not mean the list of duplicates in the banner above the question, but the list of related questions in the right sidebar:

> [image]

While the question was closed, all users saw the same banner. In the above screenshot taken now the question mentioned in the comment is no longer first, probably because the related questions list has been recalculated and some parameters were changed.

Comment: So the answer being - I can't read :)

Comment: @RGraham many people miss the sidebar, no worry... :-)

Comment: @RGraham I also don't feel comfortable winning a bounty on a rather "trivial" thing so I requested a refund. Big chance my request will be declined, but still a chance it will be handled and you'll get the rep back. :)

Comment: Very honest of you, but hey - you answered my question so imo you deserve the rep

Comment: @RGraham it's 50% of your total rep... and if I would have seen this question in time I would have answered for free. :) (but yeah, the bounty did its job just fine by drawing attention)

Comment: I'll go ahead and refund it this time. In the case that you _really_ wanted to apply it, go ahead and start it again. It'd be better if you continued to unlock privileges to help keep the place clean, imho :)

Comment: @TimPost thanks a bunch! (going to ping OP, he's not getting auto notified)

Comment: @RGraham see Tim comment above. :)